# Fastest way to transfer small files to PC

Tags: file-transfer, files

I am looking for the fastest solution to transfer many small files really fast to my PC from my Android powered phone. For example I would like to transfer 100x5KB data in a second. Is there a way if I use SSD and I have min. 50MB/s internet with 10-40ms ping (I know ping is very important). Also, no cables can be used. So it must be wireless.

I already thought of

- Network file sharing but I think it is not that fast (via WiFi)
- Bluetooth (very very slow)
- Pipe/Socket (don't really know how fast it is)

I will possibly need to transfer XML files and there will be about max. 5 meters between the PC and the mobile device.

Is there a fast way that can be handled with Java?

Thank you!

Comment: There may be a server available in Servers Ultimate Pro (on Play) that can serve your purpose, but otherwise, you'd have to use WiFi with a custom protocol of some sort, because Samba (SMB) and FTP would be too slow for you.

Comment: Server is not available for every user. It will be an app for a normal user. I will need to transfer data from the phone's sensors to GeoGebra in XML format. These are usually max. 5KB files but that is the upper maximum. FTP also requires some kind of setup before. I don't want it

Comment: Are you writing an app? If not, why not a file sync program like DropBox?

Comment: I am writing an app. And normal upload-download isn't fast enough. I am looking for strange but fast techniques

Comment: you can compress many files to one, then transfer to android phone and decompress it

Comment: The time taken for compression and decompression should also be included because this is part of the process and won't be used in any other process. It is best if an example is provided as to how much it took for a sample in question to be compressed, transferred, and later decompressed. This is also very much dependent on the efficiency of processors in the devices one would be using.

Answer (score 0):

I use [BitTorrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync) a cross platform sync program using the [P2P protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer). The files will only exist on your devices unless you set up a cloud based service to watch your file(s)/folder(s). Send & receive files of any size on any network, encrypted & visible to anyone whom you share the private key(s).

Comment: If there is only one pc and one mobile, torrent isn't fast enough, am I right?

Comment: Depends on many factors including but not limited to; bandwith, size & amount of files etc. I guess give it a trial run, see how it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for the fastest way to transfer files to your PC, try to use AirMore. With just three steps, your files will be transferred from your phone to your PC. This tool is a big help for me since I started using it.